# ssh -X: take over the actual screen

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, xorg

I can work with "ssh -X user@ip" on my remote clients so everything is setup OK.

But what I'd really want to achieve is not to have a "new" desktop through ssh, but really take over the screen. So I need to see what is on the display at that moment.

Can this be done with ssh?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: Do you mean like using a VNC?

Comment: indeed vnc without using vnc ;-)

Comment: Don't know if this helps you Frank, but you can do VNC over SSH. I can show you an example if it helps?

Comment: think SSH is not the correct way to do this. will indeed use VNC or Remote Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need x11vnc - a software that "exports" your actual (real) X display over VNC protocol: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/
You can connect to remote machine using the `-L` option of SSH to forward VNC port to your machine and execute x11vnc. So you can execute a VNC viewer in your machine to connect to VNC server through a secure connection. Execute it in your machine:

```
# creates port forward and starts x11vnc
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 -N -f user@remote-machine x11vnc

# starts VNC client
xvncviewer localhost::5900
```